# How can I make responsive grid layout in html css

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I searched over internet and couldn't find this kind of grid layout.

"grid-template-columns" doesnt do the thing, cant do one box bigger then the others. I want 4  equal boxes and 1 box with equal height and width = square box * 2 + gridgap.

here is the image I've illustrated to make you understand what i ment.

I also tried to use display flex but I didnt get the Idea of it. Please, help me. Thanks!

[Illustation of my idea](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHK0l.png)

Comment: Why is this difficult? Just tell box 5 to span 2 columns and start in column 2

Comment: Actually I am backend developer, just playing around with frontend & helping my friends to finish the project. Can you please share you idea in code. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Like in the image

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 100%;
  height: 180px;
}
.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
}
.box {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box.big {
  width: calc(20vw + 24px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box big"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Fields 1-5 directly below each other are centered to the middle at the current width

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vw;
}
.box {
  width: 10vw;
  height: 10vw;
  margin: 12px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.box.big {
  width: calc(20vw + 24px);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box big"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes man, great! Thanks! This is what I wanted. Can you please also add some css and make it responsive? I marked it as a right answer already! I want 1 box of width 100%, and the others below it.

Comment: @KamalMuradov You mean that fields 1-5 directly below each other are centered to the middle at the current width?

Comment: @Sli40 Yes! This is what exactly I mean

Comment: @KamalMuradov Ok I should have it now

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the question ("How can I make responsive grid layout in html css") is this:

```css
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
}

.box {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  width: 128px;
  min-height: 128px;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 10px;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
}

.box5 {
  grid-column: 2/5;
  max-width: 280px;
  width: 100%;
}


/*for this to be visible, the screen-width has to be under 600px*/

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .box5 {
    grid-column: 2/1;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box1 box">128x128</div>
  <div class="box2 box">128x128</div>
  <div class="box3 box">128x128</div>
  <div class="box4 box">128x128</div>
  <div class="box5 box">280x128</div>
</div>
```